# what should be the parameters in residplot seaborn

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-visualization, seaborn

I have made a simple linear regression model:

```
LR = LinearRegression()
kfold = model_selection.KFold(n_splits=10, random_state=12)
result_kfold = model_selection.cross_val_score(LR, X_train, Y_train, cv=kfold, scoring = 'r2')
print("Accuracy: %.2f%%" % (result_kfold.mean()*100.0)) 
LR.fit(X_train,Y_train)
Y_pred = LR.predict(X_test)
print("Y_pred:", Y_pred)
```

i want to plot the residual errors. I've used 'residplot' for the same. But i'm not sure if i've passed the right arguements. According to the documentation, we've to use predictor variable and result/response variable.
Here's the code:

```
sns.set(style="whitegrid")
sns.residplot(Y_test, Y_pred, lowess=True, color="g")
```

Can anyone please tell me if it is right...also what should be the labels of X and Y axis?

Thank You in advance for help

Comment: Please do write "*According*" instead of "*Acc.*"; SO is not a chat room (edited).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are plotting something very weird, so let's use an example dataset:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import matplotlib. pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

iris = sns.load_dataset('iris')

X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(iris.iloc[:,:3], iris.iloc[:,3],random_state=11)

LR = LinearRegression()
LR.fit(X_train,Y_train)
Y_pred = LR.predict(X_test)
```

If you just want to plot the residuals, you can do:

```
sns.set(style="whitegrid")
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize =(5,5))
sns.regplot(x=Y_pred,y=Y_test-Y_pred,ax=ax,lowess=True)
ax.set(ylabel='residuals',xlabel='fitted values')
```

[image]

What you are getting with sns.regplot() is the y variable regressed onto the x-variable and the residuals being plotted, which makes no sense in your case, and I illustrate below how the plot is obtained, first you fit the prediction (y variable) to actual (x variable), and get the residuals:

```
plotfit = LinearRegression()
plotfit.fit(Y_test.to_numpy().reshape(-1,1),Y_pred)
residual = Y_pred - plotfit.predict(Y_test.to_numpy().reshape(-1,1))
```

Then plotting it gives you exactly the same thing as your sns.residplot:

```
sns.set(style="whitegrid")
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2,figsize =(10,5))

sns.residplot(Y_test,Y_pred,lowess=True, color="g",ax=ax[0])
ax[0].set_xlim(0,2.5)
sns.regplot(x=Y_test,y=residual,lowess=True)
ax[1].set_xlim(0,2.5)
```

[image]

Comment: i'm not able to understand what you're trying to say, do you mean that i should use regplot? or i've used residplot inappropriately??

Comment: you have used residplot wrongly. It does another fit for you (see 2nd part of my answer). In your situation, you regplot with the code provide, that is correct

Comment: okay thankyou so much, i actually wanted a residual plot and i came across this residplot.

Comment: oh @rishitaagnihotri, sorry there was a typo, you should plot residuals vs fitted values, I have edited the answer, it is correct now

Comment: you can also check out this https://www.scikit-yb.org/en/latest/api/regressor/residuals.html

Comment: this residualplot of yellowbrick is an alternative to your method right? it plots the same

Comment: yes.. it plots the train and test at the same time, without the loess smooth and with a side histogram.. It's an alternative if you don't mind installing new packages